# Google Adsense equivalent for a long-running Flash/Silverlight apps

Tags: flash, silverlight, adsense

I'm looking for Google Adsense alternatives for a long-running Flash/Silverlight applications. It doesn't necessarily need to be hosted directly in Flash/Silverlight (although this would be sweet) but I cannot use Google Adsense because:

a) by default Google Adsense requires ads to be opened in the same browser window which involves navigating away from the page with the application. Since the application is relatively self-contained entity (a kind of an image editor) closing it is not acceptable behaviour. Altering this behaviour in Google Adsense will breach its Terms and Conditions.

b) Pages are not reloaded often. Once the user starts using Flash/Silverlight application she/he will stay on the same page for a relatively long period of time. It would be nice if an advertising component be able to automatically reload its content every few minutes.

Is there any other marketing platform which fits better to the aforementioned scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Check out MochiAds, and AdSense for Games http://www.google.com/ads/games/index.html. Most advertisement solutions for Flash will be focused on games, but that shouldn't be too much of the problem.

Silverlight is out in the cold right now. No apps -> no market -> no ad networks -> no apps...